# Joining table with multiple fields in Sql where one field needs to be summed

Tags: sql

I have two tables:

### Table GL

```
TRANS_NBR     BASE_AMOUNT    CTRL GRP
 120211282    -7200          77
 120211282    -300           77
 120211282    -10000         76
```

### Table AP

```
TRANS_NBR   BASE_AMOUNT    CODE
 120211282  7500           Wire
 120211282  10000          ACH
```

I need to be able to add the Code column to the GL Table, but the the amounts need to be aggregated first.   Does anyone know how to accomplish this?  Thanks

I've tried this from Tom Ingram's answer,

```
SELECT GLTRANS.REFERENCE, SUM(GLTRANS.BASE_AMOUNT) AS SUM_BASE_AMOUNT, CBCHECK.CODE 
FROM (      
SELECT GLTRANS.REFERENCE, GLTRANS.BASE_AMOUNT, CBCHECK.CODE         
FROM  LAWSON_PRODST.LAWSON.GLTRANS      
LEFT JOIN LAWSON_PRODTST.LAWSON.CBCHECK on CBCHECK.TRANS_NBR = GLTRANS.REFERENCE    
UNION       
SELECT GLTRANS.REFERENCE, GLTRANS.BASE_AMOUNT, CBCHECK.CODE         
FROM LAWSON_PRODTST.LAWSON.CBCHECK      
)       
GROUP BY GLTRANS.REFERENCE
```

But I get an "incorrect syntax near keyword "group." Can anyone spot the issue?  Thanks

Comment: Can `trans_nbr = 120211282` really belong both to Wire and ACH?  If so, why does table `GL` not have a `code` column?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I was pulling a query out of Excel.  Also the Trans_Nbr is really a reference # much like a check #. It really should be unique, but this is what I have to work with.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this

```
select DTABLE.TRANS_MBR, DTABLE.SUM(BASE_AMOUNT) as DTABLE.SUM_BASE_AMOUNT, CODE
from (
    select TABLE_GL.TRANS_NBR, TABLE_GL.BASE_AMOUNT, TABLE_AP.CODE
    from TABLE_GL
    left join TABLE_AP on TABLE_AP.TRANS_NBR = TABLE_GL.TRANS_NBR
    union
    select TABLE_AP.TRANS_NBR, TABLE_AP.BASE_AMOUNT, TABLE_AP.CODE
    from TABLE_AP
) as DTABLE
group by TRANS_NBR
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  TRANS_NBR,
        Base_Amount = SUM(Base_Amount),
        Code        = /*Your Logic Here */
  FROM  TABLE_GL
 GROUP BY TRANS_NBR
```